# How to maintain "this" variable inside function (typescript/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I use Jquery in my angular project.I try to access the value of **this.selectedUrl** but when it jumps into the Jquery ready function it gives UNDEFINED.How to do it?

```
this.selectedUrl = this.router.url
   console.log("this.selectedUrl",this.selectedUrl)  // gives value i.e /home
   $(document).ready(function () {
     console.log("this.selectedUrl",this.selectedUrl)  // gives undefiend
     if(this.selectedUrl=="/home"){
      console.log("this.selectedUrlIf",this.selectedUrl)
     }

  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First is angular does not need jquery to handle any functionalities. Still , in this case you are getting undefined because using of `function` key word with `$(document)`. Inside  `$(document).ready(function ()` `this` will get a complete new scope and it does not know what is `selectedUrl`. You can explore `arrow function`

Answer (score 0):

`this` takes a completely different value inside `ready` function unless you [bind `this` to the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

For example:

```
this.selectedUrl = this.router.url
   console.log("this.selectedUrl",this.selectedUrl)  // gives value i.e /home
   $(document).ready(function () {
     console.log("this.selectedUrl",this.selectedUrl)  // this is now available
     if(this.selectedUrl=="/home"){
      console.log("this.selectedUrlIf",this.selectedUrl)
     }

  }.bind(this));
```

or use the [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which take `this` from the parent scope

```
this.selectedUrl = this.router.url
   console.log("this.selectedUrl",this.selectedUrl)  // gives value i.e /home
   $(document).ready(()=>{
     console.log("this.selectedUrl",this.selectedUrl)  // this is now available
     if(this.selectedUrl=="/home"){
      console.log("this.selectedUrlIf",this.selectedUrl)
     }

  });
```

a third option is to store `this` to another variable and refer to that variable instead. For example:

```
var that = this; // store to variable
this.selectedUrl = this.router.url
   console.log("this.selectedUrl",this.selectedUrl)  // gives value i.e /home
   $(document).ready(function () {
     console.log("this.selectedUrl",that.selectedUrl)  // this is now available via that variable
     if(that.selectedUrl=="/home"){
      console.log("this.selectedUrlIf",that.selectedUrl)
     }

  });
```

**Explanation:** [`this` is a unique variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) from the rest (in Object-Oriented Programming). It gets **re-assigned to different values (with same name `this`) based on which function scope it is used**. So to keep `this` to refer to a specific instance inside another function you need to follow one of the approaches above.